# Message Box (Yes/No)

Tags: javascript

I normally show a message box this way :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('Lecturer ID already exists in the database');", true);
```

in this example it only shows one ok button, if I replace the word "alert" with "confirm" then it shows ok and cancel, I was wondering what can I put there to show yes and no ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#, and everything to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I was just too tired that I didn't realize what I was tagging this post at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no cross-browser support for opening a confirmation dialog that is not the default OK/Cancel pair.

Try Jquery UI:
http://jqueryui.com/

From **jQueryUI** you can do like this

```
$("#id").dialog({
  buttons: {
    "Yes": function() {},
    "No": function() {}
  }
});
```

Comment: note, jquery ui's modal dialog will be internal to the page. For a custom popup dialog you'd need to use [showModalDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.showModalDialog) and build a custom page for the modal dialog.